Creating an nginx redirect while removing two subdirectories from the path
I have the following nginx redirect which needs to redirect all requests to a different domain name.  It works fine.
However the request url will be like:
https://example.com/abc/123/TOKEN
How can I reformat this in the redirect to be like:
https://example.com/TOKEN
events {}
http {
server {
    listen       80  default_server;
    server_name  _;
    return 301 https://example.com/$request_uri;
}
}


The Nginx rewrite...permanent; statement can change the URL before generating a 301 redirect.
For example:
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    rewrite ^/[^/]+/[^/]+(/.*)$ https://example.com$1 permanent;
}

Note: server_name _; is no longer necessary.
